# Find lagging rows of a query omitted by a WHERE clause in SQL/SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

### Setup

I have a table of race times, listing a runner, their team, and their race time:

```sql
CREATE TABLE race (person TEXT, team TEXT, timer FLOAT);

INSERT INTO race
  (person, team, timer)
VALUES
  ("ahmed", "red", 4.3),
  ("baadur", "green", 4.4),
  ("carel", "red", 4.5),
  ("dada", "green", 4.9),
  ("eder", "green", 5.0),
  ("farai", "red", 5.1);
```

I can make a list of all people on the *red* team and their ranking:

```sql
SELECT person, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY timer) AS ranking FROM race WHERE team="red";
```

which emits

| person | ranking |
| --- | --- |
| ahmed | 1 |
| carel | 2 |
| farai | 3 |

### Question

I want to also get the name of runner who *followed* each of these red runners, i.e., who had the next slowest time—so I want:

| person | ranking | next runner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ahmed | 1 | baadur |
| carel | 2 | dada |
| farai | 3 | null |

where note how since nobody has a slower time than Farai, Farai's third column is null.

Can I do this efficiently with a single query?

#### Considerations

I'd like to avoid first getting the list of red runners and their times with one query and then making another three (or more generally `N`) queries to get the runner with the next time, e.g., this is what I do *not* want to do:

```sql
SELECT person FROM race WHERE timer>=4.3 AND person != "ahmed" LIMIT 1;
SELECT person FROM race WHERE timer>=4.5 AND person != "carel" LIMIT 1;
SELECT person FROM race WHERE timer>=5.1 AND person != "farai" LIMIT 1;
--
```

I might be able to rework this above approach to be a single query instead of multiple individual ones but I feel like it should be possible to get what I want in a single query if there was a way to run a subquery for each row that matches the `WHERE team="red"` clause to find the next row (which could be made fast by an index on `timer`), but I'm not sure if that's possible.

For example, could I use SQLite's `lag` window function to achieve this? By itself, `lag` would look at rows that met my `WHERE team="red"` criterion so it wouldn't return the next-slowest runner if they were on the green team or another non-red team.

Is there a general term for this kind of query?

There could be many teams and many runners so I'd like to know how to make this kind of lookup as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LAG` here, along with `ROW_NUMBER` with partition:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY timer) ranking,
              LEAD(person) OVER (ORDER BY timer) next_runner
    FROM race
)

SELECT person, ranking, next_runner
FROM cte
WHERE team = 'red'
ORDER BY ranking;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks Tim! Does the partitioned `ROW_NUMBER` mean SQLite has to partition the entire table? That is, will this be efficient with lots of teams and lots of rows? Is `ROW_NUMBER` smart enough here to only look at the teams I'm specifying in the `WHERE team = "red"` clause? Sorry if I'm asking a bad question or even an invalid question.

Comment: Yes, in my answer above `ROW_NUMBER` is being applied to the entire table, with a partition by team.  This mean that every team's group of records gets its own row number.  I do this because `LEAD` as you want it needs to be applied over the entire table.  We restrict to only red runners in the outer query.

Comment: Ok, got it, it makes sense that the database engine needs to enumerate the full partition and for all teams, even ones I'm not interested in, because the `LEAD` might come from one of those other teams. For performance reasons, it sounds like it might be better to add another column, "next_runner" that I explicitly populate when I insert each row in this table, and have that pre-computed instead of this very cool query?

Comment: @AhmedFasih Your above comment is spot on in its explanation.  The problem with the computed column is that what happens if your underlying data might change in the future, e.g. due to a correction?  Then you'd also have to update the `next_runner` computed column.  Because of edge cases like this, I prefer to compute the lead on the fly, to avoid extra work down the road.

Comment: Perfect, understood! Thank you very kindly ! This is a lovely query, I will study it in detail.

Comment: And for future reference, the common table expression in this query can be saved as a view, which I think will give the best of both worlds: guaranteed data integrity and fast (assuming reads far outnumber writes, since the view will be automatically recomputed following each write).